# How to get access to the target that has been instantiated in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game where I need to spawn a player in the start of the game. Then I will get transform.position of that player but I dont know how to do that. Here is my code:

```
GameObject playerball;
Transform spawpoint;
bool spaw

private void Start(){
    spaw = false;
}

private void Update()
{
   if(!spaw)
   {
       Instantiate(playerball, spawpoint.position, spawpoint.rotation);
       spaw=true;
   }

   //????????????
}
```

As you see, I have no idea how to get access to that playerball. That playerball is the prefab that holds the control script, and this script has 'Transform public Camera' but in the prefab 'public Transform Camera ' is 'None(Transform)'. So I need that, when I have instantiated the playerball, I can control it, that mean I can set which is 'public Transform camera'. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

[Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) returns a reference to the object you have just instantiated. You just have to keep that reference, and to work on it for your own needs:

```
GameObject instance = Instantiate(playerball, spawpoint.position, spawpoint.rotation);
```

Also, you are missing a semicolon on this line:

```
bool spaw
```

Whole code would then give:

```
GameObject playerball;
Transform spawpoint;
bool spaw;
GameObject playerballObject;

private void Start(){
    spaw = false;
}

private void Update()
{
    if(!spaw)
    {
        playerballObject = GameObject.Instantiate(playerball, spawpoint.position, spawpoint.rotation);
        spaw=true;

        // Do any first time modification you need on your object.
    }

    // Use your reference there to update the state of your object.
}
```

Comment: So that mean 'instance' will have the position of the'playerball' that has been spawed?

Comment: @Huy.V Exactly. It's a direct reference to the Playerball object you have instanciated in your scene. So both `transform.position` components are equal. And if you modify anything on that reference, it will affect the object in the scene.

Comment: Mind...you may want to have the `GameObject instance` declaration *outside the Update method* so that it persists longer than one frame.

Comment: It kinda depends what he wants to achieve with it. For me this Instantiate part of the code should even be put in the Start function so that it is only run once, and not in an Update like that. Maybe OP had a reason for this though.

Comment: If it's a one-time modification, then the declaration should be inside the `if(!spawn) check.` which avoids an unnecessary if(instance != null) check because the only time it won't be null is if spawn is false *which we already checked for.*

Comment: @Draco18s True that. As I am unsure what the OP final usage of the object will be except the Camera part, I modified the code so he can keep the instance's reference.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative script, making a few changes that Isuka did not, for efficiency, clean-code, and good practice.

```
public GameObject playerballPrefab;
public Transform spawpoint;
private GameObject playerballInstance;

private void Update()
{
   if(playerballInstance == null)
   {
       playerballInstance = Instantiate(playerballPrefab, spawpoint.position, spawpoint.rotation);
      // Other spawn logic / modification
   }

   //do stuff with playerballInstance every frame
}
```

Notice that we no longer need the `bool spawn` variable (er, `spaw` which is misspelled) as we can check to see if the `playerballInstance` is null, and if it is, spawn it.  Any time it is null (e.g. if it is destroyed by any means) we will spawn a new one (which I renamed to `playerballPrefab` just so that the variable's name indicates that this object is not in the scene hierarchy; purely optional), just as if `spawn` was reset to false by an external script, but without any potential conflicts (e.g. setting `spawn` to false *without* destroying the instance and vice versa).

<s>Additionally we hold that reference in perpetuity so that the ball can be acted upon continuously, rather than for the single frame it was instantiated.</s> Isuka edited their answer to include this change.

`playerballInstance` can be set as either public (because we wish an outside script to modify the value) or private (because no other script should be touching it).  The prefab and transform are declared public because presumably they are defined in the editor / inspector (and private fields are not listed and not serializable).

Start method is no longer needed because we no longer have a `spawn` value to make sure is set as we want (as well as not needed originally, as the [default value for a bool is false](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table) and the fact that we could declare `bool spawn = false` without the Start() method anyway).

Marking `Start()` and `Update()` as private is also not strictly necessary, but not wrong. Similarly marking it public is not necessary or wrong.  I personally either leave it off (inheriting its protection level from MonoBehaviour) or mark it public (as all MonoBehaviours have this method declared).  It makes no difference to the engine what protection level is used, as it is invoked [through voodoo](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/).